# I want to move a object right side at a distance and after reaching that distance, it should move at its origin place again using javascript

Tags: javascript

//css part

```
.header2
{
    height:20px;
    width:1250px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
    border-top-left-radius:50px;
    border-top-right-radius:50px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

#move1{
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
    border-top-left-radius:50px;
    border-top-right-radius:50px;
    background-color:#00F; 
    position:absolute;

    }


<html>
<body>
<div class="header2">
<div id="move1">
</div>
```

//javascript

```
<script>
function move(){
var elem = document.getElementById("move1");
var pos = 0;
var id = setInterval(frame,10);
function frame(){
    if (pos == 1150)

 //i add this part to reverse the object

{
        elem.style.right = pos + 'px';
        pos--;
        }
        else{pos++;
            elem.style.left = pos + 'px';}}}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

sorry i dont have any more details to write and other programmer can understand this code and my problem without describing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("move1");
  var container = document.getElementById("header");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  var direction = +1; // move right initially
  var maxRight = container.offsetWidth - elem.offsetWidth; // turn around position

  function frame() {
    if (pos > maxRight || pos < 0) direction *= -1; // change direction

    pos += direction;
    elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
  }
}

move();
```

```css
.header2 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#move1 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #00F;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="header2">
  <div id="move1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason it looks like it goes too far left sometimes, so you might like to use `var pos = 1;` initially, and 
`if (pos > maxRight || pos < 1) ...`

Comment: what is the use of offsetWidth?

Comment: It's the width of the element. You used a manual calculation to arrive at 'pos  = 1150',  this does the same but automatically.